# R-use dataframe's data to make histogram

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a histogram from below data:

[image]

There have five categories(screen.out~safety.out), and at the end have a total(just calculate how many "1" in each category)

This is my target plot:

[image]

But I don't know how to generate my target plot. Can it just use total number to generate a plot(all categories in one picture just like the annex2)? or other method?

Thanks for watching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datatotal %>%
select(-complaindata) %>%
 gather() %>% 
    ggplot(aes(key, value)) + 
    geom_col() +
    labs(x = "x_name", y = "y_name")
```

This should give you the plot as designed in your image.

Comment: It worked, thanks for your answer. And can it set up the Y-axis's distance ?

Comment: 1) Sure, just type `?scale_y_continuous` in your console. 2) Thanks, if you feel the answer was able to achieve your result, request you to kindly accept the answer.

Comment: The code is below :https://i.imgur.com/OhTccvs.png，and the next is the plot: https://i.imgur.com/ET06fNo.png. In the figure2,  I have marked the red circle that I want to change its ruler, because each category's length is too same to see the difference. Now, I typed (1)scale_y_continuous or (2)scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, 10)), but the plot is also displayed the same result. How can I change the  Y-axis's distance ?

Comment: Sorry, once you type in the `?command`, scroll down at the end you will find a few examples of how it works, use these to infer your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example with your data, but please next time don't post the images, copy and paste the actual code and data.

Fake data:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- tibble(
  screen.out = c(rep(1, 19), 0),
  voice.out =  c(rep(0, 15), rep(1,5)),
  cs.out = c(rep(0,10), rep(1, 10))
) # this is just some fake data
```

The trick is now to aggregate all the columns (here 3) in two columns one with the numbers and one with the original column name (it's done by `gather` below).

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

data %>% 
  gather("key", "value") %>%  # you can change this names
  ggplot(aes(key, value, fill = key)) + # as long as you update here too accordingly
  geom_col()
```

[image]